# Error 1064 in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm not an expert with MySQL and I've problems with this Stored Procedure.
I'm trying to do the SP with conditions but I don't know what is wrong here, I have a mistake:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'declare done int default 0;    declare continue
>   handler for sqlstate '02000' set' at line 16

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getListPrsn(IN idEquipo INT, IN tipo char, IN Puesto INT)
begin
declare varJefe int;
declare eqpSupJefe int;
declare jefeONo cursor for select tblpuesto.PtoLiderEqp from tblequipo 
    inner join tblpuesto   on (tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
    inner join tblplaza    on (tblpuesto.PtoID=tblplaza.PzaPto)
    inner join tblpersona on (tblplaza.PzaPrsn=tblpersona.PrsnID)
    where tblequipo.EqpID=idEquipo and tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
declare equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe cursor for select tblequipo.EqpEqpSup
    from tblequipo
    inner join tblpuesto on(tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
    where tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
if tipo="jefe"
    then
        declare done int default 0;
        declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done=1;
        open jefeONo;
            begin
                repeat
                    fetch jefeONo into varJefe;
                until done end repeat;
            end;
        close jefeONo;
        if varJefe=1
            then
                declare done int default 0;
                declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done=1;
                open equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                    begin
                        repeat
                            fetch equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe into eqpSupJefe;
                        until done end repeat;
                    end;
                close equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                call getLider(eqpSupJefe);
        else
            if varJefe=0
                then
                    call getLider(idEquipo);
            end if;
        end if;
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my SP
We have to check the declaration order
1.- variables
2.- conditions
3.- cursors
4.- handlers

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getListPrsn(IN idEquipo INT, IN tipo CHAR, IN Puesto INT)
begin
declare varJefe int;
declare eqpSupJefe int;
declare done int default 0;
case tipo
    when "jefe" then
        begin
            declare jefeONo cursor for select tblpuesto.PtoLiderEqp from tblequipo 
                inner join tblpuesto   on (tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
                inner join tblplaza    on (tblpuesto.PtoID=tblplaza.PzaPto)
                inner join tblpersona on (tblplaza.PzaPrsn=tblpersona.PrsnID)
                where tblequipo.EqpID=idEquipo and tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
            declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done=1;
            open jefeONo;
                repeat
                    fetch jefeONo into varJefe;
                until done end repeat;
            close jefeONo;
            set done=0;
            if varJefe=1
                then
                    begin
                        declare equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe cursor for select tblequipo.EqpEqpSup
                            from tblequipo
                            inner join tblpuesto on(tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
                            where tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
                        declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done=1;
                        open equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                            repeat
                                fetch equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe into eqpSupJefe;
                            until done end repeat;
                        close equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                        call getLider(eqpSupJefe);
                    end;#begin del if varJefe=1
            else
                if varJefe=0
                    then
                        call getLider(idEquipo);
                end if;
            end if;
        end;#begin del case JEFE
end case;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the part as pointed below, where you are trying to declare a local variable inside `IF .. ELSE` block. You can set the variable inside `if .. else` block but you should declare them in the beginning

```
   if varJefe=1
        then
            declare done int default 0; <-- Here
```

You should declare the variable at the beginning like

```
create procedure getListPrsn(IN idEquipo INT, IN tipo char, IN Puesto INT)
begin
declare varJefe int;
declare eqpSupJefe int;
declare done int default 0; <-- declare it here
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DECLARE` has to be at the beginning of a `BEGIN ... END` block. You can either move them to the beginning of the procedure (the variable declaration has to be before the cursors, the handler declaration has to be after them):

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getListPrsn(IN idEquipo INT, IN tipo char, IN Puesto INT)
begin
declare varJefe int;
declare eqpSupJefe int;
declare done int default 0;
declare jefeONo cursor for select tblpuesto.PtoLiderEqp from tblequipo 
    inner join tblpuesto   on (tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
    inner join tblplaza    on (tblpuesto.PtoID=tblplaza.PzaPto)
    inner join tblpersona on (tblplaza.PzaPrsn=tblpersona.PrsnID)
    where tblequipo.EqpID=idEquipo and tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
declare equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe cursor for select tblequipo.EqpEqpSup
    from tblequipo
    inner join tblpuesto on(tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
    where tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done=1;

if tipo="jefe"
    then
        open jefeONo;
            begin
                repeat
                    fetch jefeONo into varJefe;
                until done end repeat;
            end;
        close jefeONo;
        if varJefe=1
            then
                open equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                    begin
                        set done = 0;
                        repeat
                            fetch equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe into eqpSupJefe;
                        until done end repeat;
                    end;
                close equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                call getLider(eqpSupJefe);
        else
            if varJefe=0
                then
                    call getLider(idEquipo);
            end if;
        end if;
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

or put them after the `BEGIN` statements before the `REPEAT` statements:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getListPrsn(IN idEquipo INT, IN tipo char, IN Puesto INT)
begin
declare varJefe int;
declare eqpSupJefe int;
declare jefeONo cursor for select tblpuesto.PtoLiderEqp from tblequipo 
    inner join tblpuesto   on (tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
    inner join tblplaza    on (tblpuesto.PtoID=tblplaza.PzaPto)
    inner join tblpersona on (tblplaza.PzaPrsn=tblpersona.PrsnID)
    where tblequipo.EqpID=idEquipo and tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
declare equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe cursor for select tblequipo.EqpEqpSup
    from tblequipo
    inner join tblpuesto on(tblequipo.EqpID=tblpuesto.PtoEqp)
    where tblpuesto.PtoID=Puesto;
if tipo="jefe"
    then
        open jefeONo;
            begin
                declare done int default 0;
                declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done=1;
                repeat
                    fetch jefeONo into varJefe;
                until done end repeat;
            end;
        close jefeONo;
        if varJefe=1
            then
                open equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                    begin
                        declare done int default 0;
                        declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done=1;
                        repeat
                            fetch equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe into eqpSupJefe;
                        until done end repeat;
                    end;
                close equipoSuperiorDeMiJefe;
                call getLider(eqpSupJefe);
        else
            if varJefe=0
                then
                    call getLider(idEquipo);
            end if;
        end if;
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```